# Why do some questions get a negative vote?

Tags: discussion

The question on "Advanced Calculus- Ajacent zeros" has a -4 vote and is identified as [migrated].  Other questions have a -1 vote without comment.

Comment: This begs another amusing question: Where to find the worst (most downvotes) question ever posed on any given SE site?

Comment: @YvesKlett There used to be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly), but it is deleted now (10k on SO only). You can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79994/most-downvoted-questions) and switch sites to see what's the most downvoted question on each of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voting is one of the main operating principles of the Stack Exchange system, although you'll have to browse the main StackOverflow site a bit to find some general guidance. For example, [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) kind of captures the general consensus of when and how you should vote. I'm still a beginner myself...

Answer (score 3):

The comments on said [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198331/advanced-calculus-adjacent-zeros) are quite comprehensive. A bad question asked on the wrong site is likely to get downvotes and will be migrated eventually.

As for the downvotes, they are, well, downvotes. Sometimes users just cannot be bothered to comment on their reasoning (whether that is good style or not again depends very much).

Answer (score 3):

"Migrated" means a moderator moved the question to a site where it's a better fit, in this case math.stackexchange.com.

The downvotes are for two reasons:

- the question is off-topic on Mathematica.SE, as it has nothing to do with the "technical computing software Mathematica". Several users left comments on that.
- Even on Math.SE it will be a bad question. OP throws his homework in our face, not telling what he tried, or what he has problems with.

Comment: In addition, I think this was the OP's second question in a similar tone, which ticked people off... I vaguely remember seeing another bad question about an hr or so before this one (not downvoted), but I think they deleted it. This is probably what Oleksandr was referring to in his comment.

Comment: The user deleted their first question after receiving some less than encouraging but basically helpful feedback in comments (posted on the wrong site; direct copy and paste of a homework question with no context does not encourage anyone to answer; questions in the imperative are not received well on Mathematics.SE) and proceeded immediately to post a second question with the same problems. That's why I left a much less patient comment and downvoted on the second occasion.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.  Thanks.  I must say I **love** stack exchange. It's like the Boy Scouts (in a good way): merit badges, the friendly, courteous, kind pledge, all that stuff!

Comment: Down voting seems to be common for questions that appear on the outset too simple.  Regardless of their uniqueness.  This is unfortunate for a site where help and training was it's original purpose.